# Show convergence of a given series and find the limit.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Given the Series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+2)}$$

How exactly would I find out the limit is $\frac34$ as suggested by Wolframalpha? I already found out I can prove it actually converges by performing the comparison test and seeing that the underlying sequence isn't a null-sequence. But unfortunately I am absolutely clueless on how to prove that it converges to $\frac34$.

Regards,

Dennis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial fractions:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+2)}=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+2}\right)\;.$$

Now [telescope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series), and take the limit as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't heard about telescopic sums before, but from what I understand I should simply calculate $$\frac11 - \frac{1}{n+2}$$ where N is infinity, yes?

Comment: @Dennis: Not quite: $$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+2}\right)=1+\frac12-\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{n+2}\;,$$ with **two** uncancelled terms at each end. The last two tend to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, so the limit is $1+\frac12=\frac32$, and half of that is indeed $\frac34$.

Comment: Oh, you took the positive terms of the first 2 members and took the last 2 negative ones, that does make sense obviously. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Dennis: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use the integral test for verifying the series is convergent. Take $f(x)=\frac{1}{x(x+2)}$. $f(x)$ is positive and monotonic decreasing on $[1,\infty]$.

Comment: That won’t give the actual limit, though.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Yes. it gives just an upper bond. I noted here just for another approach if it is convergent. You are right absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac2{k(k+2)}=\frac1k-\frac1{k+2}\implies2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k(k+2)}=1+\frac12-\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{n+2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: rewrite $$
\frac{1}{k(k+2)}=\frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{2(k+2)}
$$

and use the telescoping property