# Calculate the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I got to this question which is extremely hard:

Calculate:

$$\frac{1}{1*3}+\frac{1}{2*4}+\frac{1}{3*5}+...$$

How would you solve a problem like this.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{1 \times 3} = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{3}\right)$

Comment: Related [Proving $\frac{1}{1\cdot3} + \frac{1}{2\cdot4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n\cdot(n+2)} = \frac{3}{4} - \frac{(2n+3)}{2(n+1)(n+2)}$ by induction for $n\geq 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391185/proving-frac11-cdot3-frac12-cdot4-cdots-frac1n-cdotn2)

Comment: Hm I cannot vote for another duplicate after canceling previous, interesting. Anyway this looks like a duplicate [Show convergence of a given series and find the limit.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227711/show-convergence-of-a-given-series-and-find-the-limit)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: let $s_n:= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+2)}$ and observe that $\frac{1}{k(k+2)}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+2})$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Aha ok, and then should I use the formula: $s=\frac{a_1}{1-q}$?

Comment: @BiliDebili No.  This is a telescoping sum.  Try writing out the first few partial sums to see what happens.

Comment: I see that things cancel out, but how to write the final sum?

Answer (score 1):

let is consider your sum
$$S=\frac{1}{1\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 4}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 5}+\frac{1}{4\cdot6}+\frac{1}{5\cdot 7}+\dots$$
Multiply $S$ by two:
$$2S=\frac{2}{1\cdot 3}+\frac{2}{2\cdot 4}+\frac{2}{3\cdot 5}+\frac{2}{4\cdot6}+\frac{2}{5\cdot 7}+\dots$$
Per fraction, write each numerator as the difference between the two components in the corresponding denominator, i.e. $2=3-1,2=4-2,2=5-3,2=6-4,2=7-5,\dots$:
$$2S=\frac{3-1}{1\cdot 3}+\frac{4-2}{2\cdot 4}+\frac{5-3}{3\cdot 5}+\frac{6-4}{4\cdot6}+\frac{7-5}{5\cdot 7}+\dots$$
Split each fraction and simplify the expression:
$$\begin{align*}
2S&=\left[\frac{3}{1\cdot3}-\frac{1}{1\cdot3}\right]+\left[\frac{4}{2\cdot4}-\frac{2}{2\cdot4}\right]+\left[\frac{5}{3\cdot5}-\frac{3}{3\cdot5}\right]+\left[\frac{6}{4\cdot6}-\frac{4}{4\cdot6}\right]+\left[\frac{7}{5\cdot7}-\frac{5}{5\cdot7}\right]+\dots \\
&=\left[\frac{1}{1}\color{red}{-\frac{1}{3}}\right]+\left[\frac{1}{2}\color{red}{-\frac{1}{4}}\right]\color{red}{+\left[\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}\right]+\left[\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{6}\right]+\left[\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}\right]+\dots}  \\
&=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}  \\
&=\frac{3}{2} \\
\end{align*}$$
Divide by two to obtain a result for $S$:
$$S=\frac{3}{4}$$
Thus,
$$\frac{1}{1\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 4}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 5}+\frac{1}{4\cdot6}+\frac{1}{5\cdot 7}+\dots=\frac{3}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

The partial sums of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k\left(k+2\right)}$ can be expressed as:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k\left(k+2\right)} = \frac{3}{4}-\frac{2n+3}{2(n+1)(n+2)}$$

The limit can be obtained:

$$\frac{3}{4}-\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{2n+3}{2(n+1)(n+2)}$$ 
And then:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{2n+3}{2(n+1)(n+2)} = \dfrac{1}{2} \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{2n+3}{(n+1)(n+2)} \\ = \dfrac{\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{2n+3}{n^2+3n+2}}{2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{2}{n}+\dfrac{3}{n^2}}{1+\dfrac{3}{n}+\dfrac{2}{n^2}}}{2}$$

And the limits of $\frac{2}{n},\frac{2}{n^2},\frac{3}{n}$ all tend to zero as $n\to\infty$. So then we have

$$\dfrac{3}{4} - \dfrac{0}{2}$$